# GKE: Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' but permissions are there?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When attempting to create a GKE cluster via gcloud, web console, or pulumi I'm receiving the error: `Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get`.

The permission for this account have `Owner`, `Editor`, and `Compute Admin`. Testing for `compute.networks.get` using the troubleshooter also shows that it is good.

Not sure why this is happening. It seemed to have been working fine the day before.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I can also run `gcloud compute regions describe us-east1 --project=myproj` as well as the list command without issue so something is not adding up.

Edit 2:
Full error is:

`googleapi: Error 403: Retry budget exhausted (5 attempts): Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/myproj/regions/us-central1'., forbidden`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with shared VPC. You need to allow the service accounts in the service project to use the sub-network with a binding resource. To do this:

Enable the permissions in the service account(s) to include 'roles/compute.networkUser' . This provides access to a [shared VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.networkUser).

I've found a similar issue on the [terraform GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1711#issuecomment-420484808), and this is the workaround a user proposed.

Also you can [disabling and then re-enabling](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#gcloud) both Compute API and Kubernetes API
You could also check the following documentation: [Enabling the Google Kubernetes Engine API in your projects](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc#enabling_the_api_in_your_projects)

Additionally at this moment Google Kubernetes Engine is reporting issues: Incident began at 2021-02-19 05:47 (all times are US/Pacific).
You can track the current status  on https://status.cloud.google.com/ and for this particular error you could check https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/container-engine/21004

> Description: We are experiencing an intermittent issue with Google Kubernetes Engine creation.
> Our engineering team continues to investigate the issue.
> We will provide an update by Friday, 2021-02-19 10:30 US/Pacific with current details.

Comment: > Also you can disabling and then re-enabling both Compute API and Kubernetes API You could also check the following documentation: Enabling the Google Kubernetes Engine API in your projects

This worked! Looks like a service account was deleted.